# Spring кириллица в аргументах get запросов

Tags: java, spring, get

Есть проект, к которому подключен Spring 3.2. через web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
    org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            ru.web.spring.api.config.ApiConfiguration
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>       org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                ru.web.spring.api.config.ApiDispathConfiguration
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Так же есть контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/rabotodatel")
public class RabotodatelController
{

@RequestMapping(value = "find_founder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getУчредители(@RequestParam(value = "fam", required = false) String fam,
            @RequestParam(value = "ima", required = false) String ima,
            @RequestParam(value = "otch", required = false) String otch,
            @RequestParam(value = "bdate", required = false) String bdate,
            @RequestParam(value = "snils", required = false) String snils,
            @RequestParam(value = "inn", required = false) String inn,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpServletRequest request)
    {
// обработка
}
}
```

Теперь суть вопроса. При поиске в строку запроса надо вводить аргументы и они будут состоять из символов кириллицы. Когда данные приходят, то вместо, к примеру, фамилии получаю какую-то не читаемую ерунду.

Первое что пришло в голову, настроить кодировку "CharacterEncodingFilter", его я прописал в web.xml, следующим образом:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Результатов это не дало, вообще никаких, пытался даже менять кодировку с "UTF-8", на что-то другое, без изменений.

Сам проект на smartgwt, а spring только для api. Как можно проверить работает ли "CharacterEncodingFilter"? Или может ещё есть способ получить корректно символы кириллицы?

Проверял просто забивая ссылку с аргументами в браузер, потом ещё спец прогой формировал запрос с заполнением заголовка (header) http, тоже не помогло.

Comment: Для точной диагностики добавьте в вопрос уточнение про "не читаемую ерунду". Например: ввожу "вася", получаю "!@#$%^"
При этом обратите внимание, что в URL по факту должны приходить только ascii а символы utf8 кодирутся. Пример `Привет=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82`

Comment: Если в браузере посылать данные, то браузер их сразу превращает в такой вид "%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D", а вот контроллер получает "Ð°Ð½Ð°ÑÐ¾Ð»Ð¸Ð¹"

Comment: А в заголовках запроса какая кодирока указана?
`contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`?

Comment: Указывал такую, но никаких изменений не было. По ходу надо уже в контроллере декодер делать